# startIndex cannot be larger then length of string. Parameter name: startIndex MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am running into an error only on my production while I am adding my weights that are on my receiving reports checked as received.

On my local machine this issue isn't exist. but on the production get the error below. 
[image]

my controller:

```
public int ReceivingReportWeight
{
    get
    {
        if (_ReceivingReportWeight == null && ReceivingReportCount > 0 && ReceivingReportWeight == 0)
        {
            dynamic receivingReportDbView = Database.Open().vw_ReceivingReports;
            List<int> receivedReceivingReports = receivingReportDbView.Select(receivingReportDbView.Id).Where(receivingReportDbView.ProjectId == Id && receivingReportDbView.Received == true).ToScalarList<int>();
            dynamic vwItemsDbView = Database.Open().vw_Items;
            int receivingReportWeight = vwItemsDbView.Select(vwItemsDbView.Weight.Sum()).Where(vwItemsDbView.ModuleId == MODULE_IDS.RECEIVING_REPORT && vwItemsDbView.TransactionId == receivedReceivingReports).ToScalar<int>();
            _ReceivingReportWeight = receivingReportWeight;
        }

        return _ReceivingReportWeight.GetValueOrDefault();
    }
}
```

my view

```
   @if (Model.ReceivingReportWeight > 0) {
        <div class="actions" style="width: 50%; text-align: right;">
            Total Received Weight: @Model.ReceivingReportWeight lbs.
        </div>
   }
```

Comment: By any chance is the string value that comes back on production empty?
I mean could you check for !string.IsNullOrEmpty(..)?

Comment: Why is getting the `ReceivingReportWeight` a property in your controller, rather than a function in your data layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error comes from something like `Substring`, when the value passed into the `startIndex` param is greater than the total length of the string. For example, if you had a string like `"Just Testing"` and you did `.Substring(12, 1)`, you'd get that exception, as the string is only 12 characters long (remember that the index is from `0`, not `1`, so the last index is `11`).

However, there is no code that you've included in your question which does anything like that. As a result, the error is being raised from somewhere else. Track down where you're working with `Substring` and figure out why your index is exceeding your string length.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share that I received this EXACT same error from incorrectly specifying a property on a control (Captcha control).

```
 Width="204px" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1">
```

I actually had entered

```
 Border="1"
```

Which fired the error indicated above. When I corrected the property name, code worked perfectly.